# finding similar record excel from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data in excel 
the list column contains the lists and the check list has some more list in it so what i want is for the list to output what is displayed in the similar record count 
it will display and count the duplicate records from the check list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in `I2` cell then drag and drop.

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$9,H2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT in I2 and drag down

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$2:$E$9=$H2))
```